I have been trying to test shippo api , but creating an internstional shipment is not working as i keep having validation error
error description
Error from shippo itself using their api reference
The Api documentation says commercial_invoice /commercialInvoice type is string , but validation says it's supposed to be a boolean .
And this property is optional but it's being required when i try making a international shipment.
  commercialInvoice?: string | undefined;
This is the error message i get
{"commercial_invoice":["Must be a valid boolean."]}
I have uninstalled the library and installed again, also tried making the commercial invoice a boolean , but i got an error that, it's a type of string.

Shippo was having conflict between their validation schema and the type returned from their api.
issue has been resolved with new version 2.2.4

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
